# Upperbounding the expected value of an L2-norm difference

Tags: probability, inequality, normed-spaces, jensen-inequality

I am trying to find an upperbound for $$E_I\left[\sum_{k=I}^n a_k^2 - \sum_{k=I}^n b_k^2\right],$$ where the expectation is taken over the random variable $I$. The tuples $a$ and $b$ are real and $I$ may take values on $\{1,...,n\}$.

I checked Jensen's inequalites but without success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the relation between $a_k,\ b_k$ and $I$?

Comment: Assuming you seek a bound on the expectation of a random length sum of fixed real numbers, clearly $||a||_2^2=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2$ is an upper bound.